# Не работает выведение истории заказов Django

Tags: python, django

Ниже на скринах будут приведены шаблоны выведения истории заказов, в админке есть сохранение ссылки на товар, который был приобретён пользователем, но при попытке выведения этих самых товаров Django не хочет отображать их информацию, нужен вывод названия товара и его картинки

```
class Order(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.PROTECT, related_name='orders', verbose_name='Заказы',
                             default=1)
    username = models.CharField(max_length=50, verbose_name='Имя пользователя')
    email = models.EmailField()
    vk_or_telegram = models.CharField(max_length=255, verbose_name='Ссылка для связи', default='vk.com')
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    paid = models.BooleanField(default=False, verbose_name='Оплачено')

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['-created',]
        verbose_name = 'Заказ'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Заказы'


    def __str__(self):
        return 'Заказ {}'.format(self.id)


    def get_cost(self):
        return sum(item.get_cost() for item in self.items.all())


class OrderItem(models.Model):
    order = models.ForeignKey(Order, related_name='order', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    product = models.ForeignKey(Posts, related_name='order_items', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)

    def __str__(self):
        return '{}'.format(self.id)

    def get_cost(self):
        return self.price
```

views.py

```
@login_required
def profile(request):
    user_orders = Order.objects.filter(user=request.user)

    data = {
        'user_orders': user_orders,
    }
    return render(request, 'store/main_pages/profile.html', data)
```

Шаблон выведения истории заказов

```
{% for item in user_orders %}
    {{ item }}
    {{ item.order }}
{% endfor %}
```

[image: Профиль]

[image: Админка]

Comment: {{ item.order.all }}

Comment: Выводит просто <QuerySet [<OrderItem: 20>]>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нашёл решение, в модели OrderItem совсем забыл про поле product, которое является ForeignKey и ссылается на сам продукт
Views.py испаравил на:

```
@login_required
def profile(request):
    user_orders = Order.objects.filter(user=request.user)
    user_order_item = OrderItem.objects.all()

    data = {
        'user_orders': user_orders,
        'user_order_item': user_order_item,
    }
    return render(request, 'store/main_pages/profile.html', data)
```

И шаблон поменял на:

```
{% if user_orders %}
   {% for item in user_order_item %}
    <p>{{ item.product.title }}</p>
    <p><img src="{{ item.product.photo.url }}" alt=""></p>
    % endfor %}
{% endif %}
```